# dividing values within vectors

Tags: r

The assignment I have is this:

> Write a function that counts the number of times the values contained in a first vector are divisible by the values contained in a second vector.
>
> The function accepts as input:
>
> a (first) vector of numbers, say `vector_dividend`;
>
> a (second) vector of numbers, say `vector_divider`;
>
> The function returns:
>
> a single number, representing how many times the values in vector_dividend are divisible by the values in vector_divisor.

For instance, if `vector_dividend=[11,13,21,15,20]` and `vector_divider=[3,5]`, then the result is 4, because: 21 and 15 are divisible by 3; and 15 and 20 are divisible by 5.

This is what I came up with but wasn't able to execute
Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you

```
vec1 <- c(10,2,3,6,20)
vec2 <- c(6,2)
div <- function(x,y){
  i<-1
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(x[i] / y[i] || y[i+1] != 1)
      add <- i
    i=i+1
  }
  return(i)
}
div(vec1,vec2)
```

Comment: In R there's a function for that, try `%%` instead of `/`.  You can change your condition to `divisionResult == 0` then and sum result using R function `sum`

Answer (score 0):

If this is an assignment I probably shouldn't come with a complete solution, but you can use `purrr` to count some of this.

```
library(purrr)
```

You can get a vector of which values in `vec2` divides *all* values in `vec1` using this:

```
map_lgl(vec2, ~ all(vec1 %% .x == 0))
```

or the values in `vec2` that divides *any* values in `vec1` like this:

```
map_lgl(vec2, ~ any(vec1 %% .x == 0))
```

If you want to count them, then, you can use one of thise:

```
sum(map_lgl(vec2, ~ all(vec1 %% .x == 0)))
sum(map_lgl(vec2, ~ any(vec1 %% .x == 0)))
```

Comment: If this is assignment and OP is only learning R then I recommended base R solution: `sum(sapply(vec2, function(x) vec1 %% x) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This line will not work:

```
if(x[i] / y[i] || y[i+1] != 1)
```

In R, there is a `%%` operator (function) which you can use like this and gives you a boolean:

```
x[i] %% y[j] == 0
```

So if you want to retain your function, we can write it like this:

```
div <- function(x,y){
  count <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(j in 1:length(y)){
      if(x[i] %% y[j] == 0){
        count = count + 1
      } else 
      {count = count}
    }
  }
  return(count)
}
```

So

```
div(vec1,vec2)

# [1] 5
```

as desired.

---

However, there are better alternatives to this in base R for this as mentioned by @PoGibas in his comment to @ThomasMailund's answer.

As mentioned by @PoGibas, you can instead write:

```
count_divs <- function(vec1, vec2) sum(sapply(vec1, function(x) x %% vec2 == 0))
count_divs(vec1, vec2)
```

Interestingly, the `div` function performs better than `count_divs` in your use case.